# How can I use category method on subclasses in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, subclassing, objective-c-category

Category methods added to specific class doesn't work at its subclass.

For me, I'm using **JSONKit** to manipulate JSON. JSONKit returns `JKArray` subclassing `NSArray`. And I have several methods added to `NSArray`. But when I execute my program, `unrecognized selector sent to instance` runtime exception thrown with the method.

How can I use the category method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding `-ObjC` flag to *Other Linker Flags* on build setting.
Here's description.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html

My `NSArray` addition and `JSONKit` codes are in separated static library, and it was not linked well without the flag. Program is working well now. And also, the linker bug described the document looks fixed.

Comment: @Deepak I need 2 more days to go :)